# Improve SQLite spatial query speeds for multilayer gpkg and Python

Tags: python, sql, geopackage, sqlite

I have a GeoPackage with two polygon layers (WGS84). The first layer is an Sentinel 2 tile grid with about 800 polygons. The other layer is about 300 000 small polygons (AOIs). Each layer has an rtree spatial index.

Tables in the gpkg:

```
[('gpkg_spatial_ref_sys',), ('gpkg_contents',), ('gpkg_ogr_contents',),
 ('gpkg_geometry_columns',), ('gpkg_tile_matrix_set',), ('gpkg_tile_matrix',),
 ('aois',), ('gpkg_extensions',), ('rtree_aois_geom',),
 ('rtree_aois_geom_rowid',), ('rtree_aois_geom_node',),
 ('rtree_aois_geom_parent',), ('sentinel2_tiles',),
 ('rtree_sentinel2_tiles_geom',), ('rtree_sentinel2_tiles_geom_rowid',),
 ('rtree_sentinel2_tiles_geom_node',), ('rtree_sentinel2_tiles_geom_parent',)]
```

I would like to check which AOIs are within which Sentinel 2 grid tile (I know about the overlaps between sentinel 2 tiles but it doesn't matter in this case as long as each AOI is assigned a tile ID). The problem I face is that that the query takes a very very long time to run. Doing geometry queries with a single layer is fairly quick (2 sec or less on average).

Currently this is the query:

```
SELECT a.fid, b.grid
FROM aois a, sentinel2_tiles b
WHERE ST_Within(ST_envelope(a.geom), ST_envelope(b.geom));
```

How can I increase/optimize the query?
Alternatively, would it be better/faster to use the OGR Within() function?

Answer (score 3):

For the moment getting the unique grid tile names first and then multiprocessing a within query for each grid tile seems to work. It reduced the query time to under a minute.
the first query which return unique grid tile IDs (list called `results`):

```
"""SELECT DISTINCT b.grid 
   FROM sentinel2_tiles b;"""
```

Second query (list of queries which is then multiprocessed):

```
query_list = [f"""SELECT a.fid, b.grid 
                  FROM aois a,
                       sentinel2_tiles b
                  WHERE b.name = '{tile}' AND
                        ST_Within(ST_envelope(a.geom),
                        ST_envelope(b.geom));"""
              for tile in results]
```